How to calculate jerk in uniform circular motion?
We can calculate the centripetal acceleration in circular motion by the equation v^2/r. But how do we calculate the jerk (which is acceleration over time)?

Jerk is "rate of change of acceleration over time", not "acceleration over time" (which doesn't really make sense).

Consider the trajectory
$$\vec{r} = r \begin{pmatrix} \sin(\omega t) \\ \cos(\omega t) \end{pmatrix}$$
Differentiate once
$$\vec{v} = \omega r\begin{pmatrix} \cos(\omega t) \\ -\sin(\omega t) \end{pmatrix}$$
Differentiate twice
$$\vec{a} = -\omega^2 r\begin{pmatrix} \sin(\omega t) \\ \cos(\omega t) \end{pmatrix} = - \omega^2 \vec{r} = -\frac{v^2}{r} \hat r$$
Differentiate thrice
$$\vec{j} = - \omega^3 r\begin{pmatrix} \cos(\omega t) \\ -\sin(\omega t) \end{pmatrix} = - \omega^2 \vec{v} = - \frac{v^3}{r^2} \hat v$$
and you got your jerk. The hat indicates a normalized vector. Also note (thank you @JEB) that since $\vec{a} = const. \vec{r}$, the derivatives repeat themselves periodically modulo a multiplicative constant $-\omega^2$ or, if you like normalized vectors, $\frac{v^2}{r}$. The $2n^{\text{th}}$ derivative thus reads
$$
\frac{\partial^{2n}}{\partial t^{2n}} \vec r = \left( -\omega^2 \right)^n \vec r = ( -1)^n \frac{v^{2n}}{r^{2n-1}} \hat r
$$
and the $(2n+1)^{\text{st}}$
$$
\frac{\partial^{2n+1}}{\partial t^{2n+1}} \vec r = \left( -\omega^2 \right)^n \vec v = ( -1)^n \frac{v^{2n+1}}{r^{2n}} \hat r
$$

Minor comment the word for take the derivative is differentiate not derive.

True, but then the metrum of my poem is screwed :(

Minor comment: the metre of your poem :-)

you missed a change to note that the n-th derivative of position goes like $v^n/r^{n-1}$.

I made some changes for the sake of scientific accuracy ;)

@RefikMansuroglu you're welcome. I only noticed that when I read your answer, and the fact that you can take through $n=0$...because we have $\ddot r = v^2/r$ memorized, but I always left it at that.
